# How can I disable the debug console from showing the file address in my code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I created a simple program for training purposes in Visual Studio Community Edition 2017 and I'm not having an issue running the program itself but it is showing me the file address for the process its running in the middle of the code in the Debug Console. I'm not sure how to disable this from showing.

I've tried searching Google but honestly I'm not sure how to easily phrase my question so no results really helped.

The program runs perfectly fine with no errors. This is a visual issue

[Highlighted area is what I want to get rid of.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTnTt.png)

Comment: Glad you have your answer. A tip. For small programs, it's much easier just to open the VS Developer Command Prompt and compile single-source files from the command line. The VS compiler is `cl.exe`. A simple compile string would be `cl /nologo /W3 /Ox /FeNameYourExe /Tp YourCPPSource.cpp` (no worrying about projects, no worrying about IDE settings, simply compile as many short programs as you like) It's up to you. `cl /?` will list all compiler options.

Comment: See also [Run the command prompt from inside Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with:

```
Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console
```

Here is a corresponding fragment from the [Visual Studio documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/general-debugging-options-dialog-box?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(VS.ToolsOptionsPages.Debugger.General)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=vs-2017):

> **Automatically close the console when debugging stops:**
>
> Tells Visual Studio to close the console at the end of a debugging session.